# Multiple COUNT and GROUP BY in a single Statement

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using DISTINCT, LEFT JOIN, COUNT and GROUP BY in single statement, like this:

```
SELECT distinct r.sid as sid, s.name as sname, s.image as simage, 
COUNT(r.sid) as scount FROM batch_request r LEFT JOIN student_info s ON s.id = r.sid 
WHERE r.tid='22' group by r.sid
```

Encoded JSON Looks like this:

```
{ "students":
[
{
"sid":"1",
"sname":"Sonali Kohli",
"simage":"22",
"scount":"3",
"sconfirmed":null,
"sdeclined":null
},
{
"sid":"2",
"sname":"Sona Ali Khan",
"simage":"22",
"scount":"3",
"sconfirmed":null,
"sdeclined":null
}
],"success":1
}
```

Table:

[image]

As you can see in above image, I have total 6 records in a table (3 for sid = 1 and 3 for sid = 2)

Status for sid 1 records (2 Confirmed  [where value is 1] and 1 Declined [where value is 2]), in a same way Status for sid 2 records (1 Confirmed [where value is 1] and 2 Declined [where value is 2])

Same thing I want to get through my QUERY which I have posted above to encode data into JSON, as you can see, still I am getting null for both the JSON objects (i.e: Confirmed and Declined)

**QUESTION 1:** What should be the **values** of `sconfirmed` and `sdeclined` for *both the objects* of **JSON** ?

**ANSWER 1:** In case of `sid = 1` (*sconfirmed* = 2 and *sdeclined* = 1) and for `sid = 2` (*sconfirmed* = 1 and *sdeclined* = 2)

**QUESTION 2:** What is `sconfirmed` and `sdeclined` in a database table ?

**ANSWER 2:** `sconfirmed` is just the **count** of records where *status* is `1` for a particular **sid** and `sdeclined` is the **count** of records where *status* is `2` for a particular **sid**

Comment: What should be the values of `sconfirmed` and `sdeclined` for both the objects of JSON ?

Comment: In case of sid = 1 (sconfirmed = 2 and sdeclined = 1) and for sid = 2 (sconfirmed = 1 and sdeclined = 2) @AlokPatel

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: what's wrong here, why it has been downvoted ? May I know the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT distinct r.sid as sid, s.name as sname, s.image as simage, COUNT(r.sid) as scount, 
SUM(CASE r.status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sconfirmed, 
SUM(CASE r.status WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sdeclined, 
SUM(CASE r.status WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as spending  
FROM batch_request r LEFT JOIN student_info s ON s.id = r.sid 
WHERE r.tid='22' 
GROUP BY r.sid
```

Comment: hey thanks for posting, sorry I forgot to tell you I have one more status called 0 as pending, apart from confirm (i.e  1) and decline (i.e  2)

Comment: And you want it counted also? Do you have a variable for it? If you don't need information about status pending then the above code should work correct.

Comment: You can use the same approach. I'll update my answer to add it.

Comment: yes I would like to count it ... :) and for that I have defined variable as spending in JSON

Comment: It's added to my answer.

Comment: thanks for showing easiest way of doing this complicate work